# Using recode and case_when together

Tags: r, dplyr

Table1$subject contains the variables "Biology", "Chemistry", and "Physics".
For Table 2, I want to recode this, to replace all instances of Biology/Chemistry with 1 and all instances of Physics with 0.

I tried the following code, since I believe this is achievable using the recode and case_when commands:

```
    Table2 <- recode(Table1, case_when(
    .$subject <= "biology" ~ 1,
    .$subject <= "chemistry" ~ 1,
    .$subject <= "physics" ~ 0))
```

Currently, I get an error message saying "case_when must be a two-sided formula, not a logical". I'm new to R so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Really grateful if anyone has any ideas!

Answer (score 5):

Both [`recode`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html) and [`case_when`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) operate on vectors, not data frames. So to create a new data frame you need to first call [`mutate`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html), and then within `mutate` use either `recode` or `case_when` to create a new column (or overwrite an existing one).

(Also, as of the latest dplyr release you no longer need to use the `.$` when using `case_when`)

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~subject,
  "chemistry",
  "biology",
  "physics"
)

df %>% 
  mutate(subject2 = case_when(
    subject == "chemistry" ~ 1,
    subject == "biology" ~ 1,
    subject == "physics" ~ 2,
  ))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     subject subject2
#>       <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 chemistry        1
#> 2   biology        1
#> 3   physics        2

df %>% 
  mutate(subject2 = recode(
    subject, 
    "chemistry" = 1,
    "biology" = 1,
    "physics" = 2,
  ))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     subject subject2
#>       <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 chemistry        1
#> 2   biology        1
#> 3   physics        2
```

Answer (score 3):

This reminded me of when I first started working with R, too, and I walked over and asked the data scientists this very same question.

They shared with me a different approach that is generally preferable in these situations. I have looked back many times and appreciated learning it early on.

The database normalization approach (unless someone out there can help us with a better name) involves mapping your code values into a separate dataframe. Then you take that collection of mapped values and `join` them to the dataframe you are wanting to encode.

This helps keep the *code* more strictly responsible for *manipulations*, and the *dataframes* responsible for holding *values/data*. This not only can speed up much of your work, saving you from hand-coding in hard-coded lookup tables, but in the longer term it will make it much easier when someone is debugging or performing modifications and re-developments.

The normalized data management approach then would look like:

```
# your code mapping
df_map <- tribble(~subject,    ~subj_cd,
                  "chemistry", 1,
                  "biology",   1,
                  "physics",   0)

# a dummy raw dataframe that you might be wanting to encode
df_raw <- tibble(stud_id = 2678:2877,
                 subject = sample(c("chemistry",
                                    "biology",
                                    "physics",
                                    "astronomy"), 200, replace = TRUE))

# encoding the data
df_coded <- 
    df_raw %>% 
    left_join(df_map)
df_code
```

> ```
> > df_coded
> # A tibble: 200 x 3
>    stud_id   subject subj_cd
>      <int>     <chr>   <dbl>
>  1    2678   physics       2
>  2    2679   physics       2
>  3    2680   biology       1
>  4    2681 astronomy      NA
>  5    2682 chemistry       1
>  6    2683 chemistry       1
>  7    2684   physics       2
>  8    2685 chemistry       1
>  9    2686 chemistry       1
> 10    2687 astronomy      NA
> # ... with 190 more rows
> ```

If you find yourself needing a quick and easy way to build longer code maps (or, especially, share them with other folks), then you will probably find Jenny Brian's `googlesheets` package very helpful (she's a member of team `tidyverse`) A really [helpful vignette for it can be found here](https://rawgit.com/jennybc/googlesheets/master/vignettes/basic-usage.html)